# Highchart not labelling null points

Tags: highcharts

I'm implementing syncing of the disconnected high charts. searchPoint() gives the left or right point instead of returning the null data point. How can I not show the marker when crosshair is on the null data point and show null label value?

```
handleMove(e) {
  let chart, point, event, indexValue;
  chart = this.refs[this.props.id].getChart();
  event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
  point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point
  if (point)
    indexValue = point.index;
  this.syncCrossHair(indexValue, e);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can write your own searchPoint() function which will include null points.  E.g. like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jj6a9jot/5/

Comment: Thanks a lot @morganfree, it worked!